# Different scaling methods affect SVM regression performance way too much

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, normalization, scaling

I have a dataset with 1000 rows and 8 columns. I am doing regression with SVM, using scikit's svm.SVR. Then I do a grid search with cross-validation on some of the parameters.
My grid looks like this:

> grid = [   {'C': [.1,1,10,50,100,500,1000], 'kernel': ['linear']},
>   {'C': [.1,1,10,50,100,500,1000], 'gamma': [0.001, 0.0001, 'auto'],
>   'kernel': ['rbf']},   {'C': [.1,1,10,50,100,500,1000], 'gamma':
>   [0.001, 0.0001, 'auto'], 'kernel': ['sigmoid']},   {'C':
>   [.1,1,10,50,100,500,1000], 'gamma': [0.001, 0.0001, 'auto'], 'kernel':
>   ['poly'], 'degree':[2,3,4]}  ]

I know this grid seems large, but I think trying different kernels with SVM is important.

When I scale my data to have 0-mean and unit variance, 2 features remained a little skewed and have min values around -14. So it may not be the best scaling method for my data.

Whereas if I use scikit's MinMaxScaler, the data is stuck between -1 and +1; and histograms look pretty normal for those 2 skewed features as well.

When I run the grid search with MinMax scaled data, I get the results within a few seconds.

When I run the grid with standard scaled data, the cross validation never ends and I need to stop the execution. I think the longest I've run it for is for 1.5 hours.

I know the kernel trick works by mapping the entire dataset to higher-dimensional space and that SVM works by calculating distances between those datapoints, and finding the margin can be difficult as well. But **WHY** would this little difference cause such a big difference in the performance???

Comment: I figured it out since asking the question. The c-parameter was too high so the optimisation problem was becoming insolvable when data was preprocessed with StandardScaler.